# How to restore my Mac Safari bookmarks and history after iCloud sync?

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, safari, data-synchronization

I have various Safari bookmarks on my iPhone. I got a new Mac laptop, and when I enabled iCloud on the Mac, all the bookmarks and history from my iPhone were copied over to my Mac. I did **NOT** want that.

How do I restore the bookmarks and the history that I formerly had on my Mac?

I am using iOS 10 and Mac OS 10.12 (Sierra).

Comment: Is it possible they were merged? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21476/how-do-i-get-safari-macs-bookmarks-to-overwrite-safari-ios-bookmarks

Also, if it was a new Mac, did you have any bookmarks on it? *Are you really asking how to keep your Mac and iOS bookmarks separate?*

Comment: @studiohack: Yes, I did have some new bookmarks and favorites on my new Mac. How do I recover them?